# I need to run script on a remote Google Cloud Virtual Machines, Is there anything similar to Azure VM extensions available on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

I want to run a script on remote virtual machines to install some applications and configure those applications. Azure virtual machine (VM) extensions are small applications that provide post-deployment configuration and automation tasks on Azure VMs. I need a similar feature for the Google Cloud Platform. Is there any way I can run a script on already deployed Virtual machines on GCP?

Comment: Do you mean startup scripts or commands that run after a VM is launched? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux Which Azure feature are you referring to (link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No.

- No, you haven't the same easiness in GCP that you have with Azure.
- Yes, you can do it by creating a SSH connection and executing your command remotely. It required more SysAdmin skills and it's less convient, but you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options for this.
You can use powershell to remotely connect and update.  (Make sure only you can connect to powershell remotely.)

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/connecting-powershell

As previously described ssh
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/windows-ssh

And if you get locked out somehow use the serial access console.  The google docs link to it is broken and goes back to rdp at the moment.

However this article by Doit goes through the details of how to use it.
https://www.doit.com/restoring-windows-server-access-via-your-google-cloud-serial-console/